# Change RGB value to a single value by converting its RGB without a loop

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have a coloured image `img`.  Now, I want to create a new NumPy array based on the RGB value of the image.  I can do this by doing a loop, based on img values and compute the new array value based on the RGB values: say, `newVal = R * val + G * val2 + B * val3`. The `newVal` will then be appended to a NumPy array variable `newNumpyVar`.

Say I have this

```
img = [[[1 2 3] [0 0 1] [ 1 1 1]] [[0 0 0] [1 1 1] [ 0 0 0]]]
```

Its a 3 x 2 image. The results should be a 6 `newVal` array. 1st array is `1*1 + 2*2 + 3*3`, 2nd array is = `0*1 + 0*2 + 1*3`, 3rd is = `1*1 + 1*2 + 1*3` and so on.

I know that there is a way to do this in a NumPysh way.  But I just don't know how.

Comment: Could you add a sample of the solution you have tried ?

Comment: Show a sample. There are many possible interpretations of the things you're describing. Please show an MCVE

Comment: Please format the code as code. It's very hard to read right now

Comment: I've flipped my vote and retracted my close vote. Thanks for updating your question and staying responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a sum-product of your image with a list of weights. If you have an image `img` of shape `(M, N, 3)` and weights `vR`, `vG`, `vB`, you can do any of the following to get a weighted `(M, N)` image:

```
img @ [vR, vG, vB]
np.dot(img, [vR, vG, vB])
np.einsum('mnc,c->mn', img, [vR, vG, vB])
np.sum(img * [vR, vG, vB], axis=-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest, but without control of how much each channel contributes (`color_im` is a numpy array):

```
gray_im = color_im.mean(axis=-1)
```

With weights:

```
gray_im = color_im[...,0]*R_weight + color_im[...,1]*G_weight + color_im[...,2]*B_weight # assumes RGB ordering of channels
```

The weighted version can be equivalently rewritten as:

```
gray_im = (color_im * np.array([R_weight, G_weight, B_weight])).sum(axis=-1)
```

Comment: Broadcasting is a much simpler way than the second snippet

Comment: @MadPhysicist I'm not quite sure the version with broadcasting is much easier to read tbh...

Comment: `np.sum(color_im * [R_weight, G_weight, B_weight])`. Not much better, but still...

Comment: Say I have this img = [[[1 2 3]  [0 0 1] [ 1 1 1]] [[0 0 0] [1 1 1] [ 0 0 0]]].  Its a 3 x 2 image.  The results should be a 6 newVal array.  1st array is = 1*1 + 2*2 + 3*3, 2nd array is = 0*1 + 0*2 + 1*3, 3rd is = 1*1 + 1*2 + 1*3 and so on.

Comment: IIRC, you still need to specify the axis for `sum`, or this will add everything together...

Comment: @RJUy. Please use the `edit` button beneath your question to make the question clear. And don't forget to format properly. There are instructions for that when you edit.

Comment: @RJUy your image should be a numpy array of shape `(3,2,3)` (height: 3, width: 2, 3 channels). The result is a single-channel image with shape `(3,2)`.